# Why there is no typical cells

Tags: cell-biology, physiology

My physiology book says that cell specialization is so great that no cell in the body could be called **a** **typical cell**.

I don't understand the above sentence, why couldn't there be typical cells? After mitosis don't we get two typical cells? Or what is meant by the sentence??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its because there are different kinds of cells in our body for example a neuron can't represent different types of cells found in our body like goblet cells etc., just like F1 car can't be representative of all cars. I presume that the word typical is in the context of human body.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about language, not Biology.

Comment: It is about biological terminology which is relevant. Asmaa in this case a "typical cell" would be a cell that represents all cells in the body equally well, like an average of all cells in the body..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical here means representative of the whole.

from the google dictionary

> typ·i·cal ˈtipik(ə)l/Submit adjective having the distinctive qualities
>   of a particular type of person or thing. "a typical day"
>   synonyms: representative, classic, quintessential, archetypal, model,
>   prototypical, stereotypical, paradigmatic;

There is such a variety of cells in the body no one is really typical.  Like a typical human.  Who would that be?  Me?  Chinese lady?  Indian kid?  There are many of us and a lot of variety.  Maybe you could say "typical older Scotsman" or "typical arrogant Stack Question answerer".  You could definitely say "typical liver cell"; narrowing down the zone limits the variety possible and lets you more accurately characterize a call as prototypical or representative.